# Parsing C++ command line arguments with optional parameters using optionparser.h

Tags: c++

All the examples in the optionparser.h (Lean Mean C++ Option Parser) file look to not use any parameters to options. And I readily admit I'm not a brilliant C++ programmer. I just wand to have some options that take a numeric parameter.
Something like [--help --count_to 5 --jump 3 --noecho].

Here is a clip from the file on usage:

```
    enum  optionIndex { UNKNOWN, HELP, PLUS, SKIP1, SKIP2};
    const option::Descriptor usage[] =
    {
     {UNKNOWN, 0, "", "",option::Arg::None, "USAGE: MyPgm [options]\n\n" "Options:" },
     {HELP, 0,"h", "help",option::Arg::None, "  --help -h \tPrint usage and exit." },
     {PLUS, 0,"p","plus",option::Arg::None, "  --plus, -p  \tIncrement count." },
     {SKIP1, 0,"","nodcs",option::Arg::None, "  --nodcs, \tMy Option1" },
     {SKIP2, 0,"","noacs",option::Arg::None, "  --noacs, \tMy Option2" },
     };

  int main(int argc, char* argv[])
  {
    argc-=(argc>0); argv+=(argc>0); // skip program name argv[0] if present
    option::Stats  stats(usage, argc, argv);
    option::Option options[stats.options_max], buffer[stats.buffer_max];
    option::Parser parse(usage, argc, argv, options, buffer);
 
    if (parse.error())
      return 1;
 
    if (options[HELP] || argc == 0) {
      option::printUsage(std::cout, usage);
      return 0;
    }
 
    std::cout << "--plus count: " <<
      options[PLUS].count() << "\n";
 
    for (option::Option* opt = options[UNKNOWN]; opt; opt = opt->next())
      std::cout << "Unknown option: " << opt->name << "\n";
 
    for (int i = 0; i < parse.nonOptionsCount(); ++i)
      std::cout << "Non-option #" << i << ": " << parse.nonOption(i) << "\n";
  }
```

I see that option::Arg can be NONE or Optional, but I am at a loss exactly
how to reference an optional argument. I am also certain that this code can do much more than I am asking it to do at this time.

Comment: This: "Demonstrates handling various types of option arguments (required, numeric,...) " - http://optionparser.sourceforge.net/example__arg_8cc.html

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that particular example. I was missing some of the important code when I copied out of the optionparser.h directly.